# Dynamic tables EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Can anyone help me figure out the correct syntax to dynamically set the tables? I have tried reflection and a switch but can't figure it out.

Issue is I can't seem to return `DbSet<object>`.

**Goal**: pass in table name as string

```
private async DbSet<object> GetBaseQuery(TableNamesEnum table)
{
    return table switch
    {
        TableNamesEnum.TblCases => _context.TblCases,
        TableNamesEnum.TblCompanies => _context.TblCompanies,
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException(),
    };
}

public async Task<PaginationResponse<GetOptionListResponse>> GetOptionList(GetOptionListRequest request)
{
    var labelField = request.LabelField.ToString();

    var query = GetBaseQuery(request.TableName).Where(c =>
        EF.Property<string>(c, labelField).Contains(request.SearchText)).Select(c => new GetOptionListResponse()
    {
        Label = EF.Property<string>(c, labelField),
    }).Distinct();

    var response = await query.Paginate(request.Page, request.PerPage).ToListAsync();

    return new PaginationResponse<GetOptionListResponse>
    {
        MaxResults = response.Count(),
        Page = request.Page,
        PerPage = request.PerPage,
        Results = response
    };
}
```

Comment: Is this for a webpage? Having the table name as a input parameter seem like a dangerous thing to do if there is any chance at all that a malicious user could change it.

Comment: Hey @JonasH, its for an api and the table names are restricted by an enum. Cheers

Comment: @Ben EF Core and DbContext are already fully dynamic. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit of Work, not a connection and doesn't deal with tables. `GetBaseQuery` is actually a bug. You already know which entity you want. If you absolutely have to, use `_conetxt.Set<Company>` to access the entity set (not query, entity set. That holds the mapping metadata). Your parameter is the entity type, not the name of the entity

Comment: Same for the rest of the code. `Where` accepts a generic expression, so `GetOptionList` isn't useful. If you know which field you want, pass it as an expression. Even that may be too much. The query you really want is `var query=_context.Companies.Where(c=>c.SomeField.Contains(text));`. That's less code than the "generic" one. To get the count, `var count=query.Count();`. To get the first page, `var page=query.Take(PageSize).ToList();`. To take the Nth page `var page=query.Skip((N+1)*PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList()`

Comment: I want to pass in the table name as a string.... that is the goal, is this not possible with EF? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Application entity, not table. If you keep thinking of tables you'll never be able to use EF or understand why you're doing things wrong. EF is an ORM, its job is to give the impression of working with in-memory application entities, not tables and rows. At some point you *do* know what the actual entity is. Why not make your code truly generic, ie using `T` type parameters instead of strings?

Comment: Besides, if you can write `TableNamesEnum.TblCases` you can create a `Dictionary<string,Type>` that maps those names to types. The `switch` expression in `GetBaseQuery` is doing the same thing as that dictionary but throws if the wrong table is passed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is because i am passing it from client application into my api so i will never know the type, okay perfect i like the dictionary approach i think. cheers

Comment: You do know the type, it's either in the URL or the controller you use. Both GraphQL and ASP.NET Core OData work with EF without (visibly) resorting to strings. URLs are routed to the correct strongly-type controller by ASP.NET Core itself. In fact, if you want a client-controlled API why not use GraphQL and HotChocolate directly?

Answer (score 0):

This was the code I was looking for

```
public static class EntityFrameworkHelper
{
    public static IQueryable<object> Set(this DbContext context, Type T)
    {
        var method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethods().Single(p =>
            p is { Name: nameof(DbContext.Set), ContainsGenericParameters: true } && !p.GetParameters().Any());

        method = method.MakeGenericMethod(T);

        return (method.Invoke(context, null) as IQueryable<object>)!;
    }
}
```

```
private readonly Dictionary<TableNamesEnum, Type> _tableTypeDictionary = new()
{
    { TableNamesEnum.TblExample, typeof(TblExample) },
};

public OptionListService(CaseManagementDbContextBase context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public async Task<PaginationResponse<GetOptionListResponse>> GetOptionList(GetOptionListRequest request)
{
    var labelField = request.LabelField.ToString();

    if (!_tableTypeDictionary.TryGetValue(request.TableName, out var entityType))
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    var query = _context.Set(entityType).AsQueryable();
}
```

It allows me to dynamically set the type. Cheers

Comment: Amended how is this @PanagiotisKanavos, just checked and its working :))), that method doesnt seem to exist? Maybe the version im using....

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos without adding the custom extension method i get The type arguments for method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried var x = _context.Set(typeof(MyObject)). (obviously i wouldnt do this its just to show the error), i used your dictionary idea to map them. With my extension the code works as expected but cant understand why it needs it, i have correct version of entity framework too.

Comment: There's no `MyOjbect` in this answer. After the edit there's a type named `T`. So the code you need to call is `context.Set(T)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my object was just an example..., i get it from my dictionary. will post full code above.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos see above code used, confirm it works with extension method but not without